# Active Model Forbidden attributes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

would someone be able to help me understand this error. I am trying to create a contact form in rails following the building web apps tutorial. I followed the steps to generate a message scaffold. I then amended my routes. Next it said to put this into the messages controller show action.

```
if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for Your Message'
  format.html { redirect_to root_path }
```

I have done this and i am getting the following error
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in MessagesController#create
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

This is my message controller file

```
class MessagesController < InheritedResources::Base 
  def show
     if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for Your Message'
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
     end
  end
end
```

My routes file is as follows

```
# devise_for :users
```

resources :products do 
  resources :orders, only: [:new, :create]
  #tells rails needs product id number
end

```
  # get 'pages/payment'

  get 'home/about'

  get 'messages/new'

  get 'seller' => "products#seller"

  get 'sales' => "orders#sales"

  get 'static_pages/productlanding'

  get "content/veg"

  get "content/fruit"

  get "content/mix"

  get 'subscriptions/new'

  root 'static_pages#home'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have managed to sort this with the following! Thanks for all the help

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /messages
  # GET /messages.json
  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  # GET /messages/1
  # GET /messages/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /messages/new
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  # GET /messages/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /messages
  # POST /messages.json
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /messages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /messages/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.update(message_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /messages/1
  # DELETE /messages/1.json
  def destroy
    @message.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_message
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    end

    .
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :company, :phone, :subject, :body)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Why are you *saving* in the *show* action?

--

**Params**

The `ForbiddenAttributes` error stems from the [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) functionality of Rails.

When saving data, you're meant to pass the params through to your model through a `strong_params` method. This is typically achieved with the following setup:

```
#app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
   end

   def new
      @message = Message.new
   end

   def create
      @message = Message.new(message_params)
      @message.save
   end

   private

   def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:your, :message, :params)
   end
end
```

This is how your `controller` should really be constructed. Your error, I believe, is caused by your lack of params to pass through to the attributes in your model (hence your call to `@save` resulting in trying to populate your model with non-data).

Comment: i have added my routes above

Answer (score 1):

Strange. You execute saving method in "show" method of controller which responsible for showing up the content on the separate page.

You should replace as following:

```
def create
  if @message.save
   flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for Your Message'
   format.html { redirect_to root_path }
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, i did this but then i get this error       undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Yes, because @message within "create" method is empty.

You should define '@message' by some data like this:

'@message' = Message.new(:message_param)

Comment: Exactly. Put it in 'create' method

Comment: thanks that makes more sense now...I tried my own version and the what you suggested and both times i get a new error

Comment: Missing template messages/create, inherited_resources/base/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :arb]}.

Comment: what do you have in routes file?

Comment: add following into routes.rb

resources :messages

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same error. The fix was to make the params function name same as the root tag of the post json like below

Post json
{"jobseeker_certificate":{"id":-1,"name":"First Class Medical Certificate","institute":"GACA","attachment":null}}

In Controller i changed jobseeker_aircraft_type_ratings_params  to jobseeker_certificate_params

```
 def  jobseeker_certificate_params
  params.require(:jobseeker_certificate).permit(:aircraft, :total_time, :pilot_in_command,
                                                :co_pilot, :rating_expiry_date, :from, :to, :jobseeker_id, :grade, :institute, :attachment, :name,
                                                :from, :to, :jobseeker_id, :grade, :institute, :attachment, :name, :sector_id, :certificate_type,
                                                :details, :certificate_type, :details)
end
```