# Ruby On Rails:recieve json, parse and save in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I want post a json to rails controller and then save each of json to database by separate controller.

For this, I post this json to rails controller:

```
            jsonList = {
                "table": {column1:"column1",column2:"column2"},
                "record": {name:"record 1"}
            };
```

and recieve below json in rails controller:

```
Started POST "/api/calculate.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-19 00:52:13 +0330
Processing by Api::V1::CalculateController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"table"=>{"column1"=>"column1", "column2"=>"column2"}, "record"=>{"name"=>"record 1"}, "calculate"=>{"table"=>{"column1"=>"column1", "column2"=>"column2"}, "record"=>{"name"=>"record 1"}}}
```

But I get below error in rails server log before I do anything:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template api/v1/calculate/create, api/v1/base/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/mgh/Documents/Maliat/sama/app/views"
):
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:124:in `find'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `find_template'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:41:in `determine_template'
```

I search for this error, but don't find any usefull guide.

`RailsController`:

```
class Api::V1::CalculateController < Api::V1::BaseController
  require 'json'
  def create
    ....
  end
end
```

I have another question. I want save each json to database by separate controller. For example I have a `RecordController` and use `create` action by below code:

```
def create
    temp = Record.new(params[:record])
    temp.save
end
```

and this type:

```
def create
   temp = Record.create(params[:record])
end
```

**but I get below error in server log**:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
  app/controllers/api/v1/calculate_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

`RecordController`:

```
class Api::V1::RecordController < Api::V1::BaseController
  require 'json'
  def create
    @data = Record.create(record_params)
    @data.save
    respond_with(@data)
  end
  private
  def record_params
    params.require(:record).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

How can I fix this problems?

Comment: Can you please give me the Model(Calculate) fields and Structure. In which table you have to store table and record content.

Comment: I don't have `calculate Model`, I want just get json from client side in this controller and save data in json with other controller, like `record` that I post in question. Note: I use angularjs for client side.

Comment: So this is the json {
                "table": {column1:"column1",column2:"column2"},
                "record": {name:"record 1"}
            }; where you want to store into Database???

Comment: At first I want separate 2 json and then post each of them in special controller. For example, I want save `"record":{name:"record 1"}` in database by RecordController that I put this controller in question and save `"table"` with a same controller like `RecordController`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the use of strong parameters features in Rails. A similar question is also answered here: [Active Model Forbidden attributes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845518/active-model-forbidden-attributes-error)

Answer (score 0):

Why you wanna split JSON and send to two separate controllers instead of that create one controller method and parse your JSON and store into the database,

JSON format:

```
{
  "table": {column1:"column1",column2:"column2"},
  "record": {name:"record 1"}
};
```

Controller method:

```
def create_record_and_table
  record = params[:record]
  @record = Record.new(:name => record['name'])
  @record.save

  table = params[:table]
  @table = Table.new(:column1 => table['column1'], :column2 => table['column2'])
  @table.save
end
```

Comment: I have more than 10 element for each json. This json is sample just for this question. I do this style now, but I have to change this method if I can.