# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError from model form.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a form to create a new model instance:

```
class Pokemon < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :trainer
    attr_accessor :name
end
```

On the page:

```
<h1>Create a New Pokemon</h1>
<%= simple_form_for(@pokemon) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name  %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

With controller:

```
class PokemonsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @pokemon = Pokemon.new
  end

  def create
    @pokemon = Pokemon.new(params[:pokemon]) #error stack comes from here
    @pokemon.trainer = current_trainer
    if @pokemon.save
      redirect_to trainer_path(current_trainer)
    end
  end

  private

  def pokemon_params
    params.require(:name).permit(:trainer)
  end
end
```

But I keep running into the following error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

I tried adding in the params.require(...).permit(...)  as per [Active Model Forbidden attributes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845518/active-model-forbidden-attributes-error) but to no luck. Any insight as to what might be wrong? I'm pretty new to rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
params.require(:pokemon).permit(:name)
```

Change your create action:

```
def create
  ...
  @pokemon = Pokemon.new(pokemon_params)
  ...
end
```

Comment: Nope still getting the same thing

Comment: Did you try this `@pokemon = Pokemon.new(pokemon_params)` ?